# OpenNMS skipping certain JMX MXBeans while collection

Tags: monitoring, jmx, collectd, opennms, mxbean

I have exposed an MBean NotifyFailedTriggers that exposes an Integer value. I have configured the poller, collectd and jmx-datacollection config files correctly. However, the collectd daemon seems to be skipping the mbean saying it is not registered. See the attached log.

> 2018-06-12 13:08:41,204 DEBUG [pool-10-thread-8] o.o.n.j.i.DefaultJmxCollector: Collecting MBean (objectname=com.example:name=notifyFailedTriggers, wildcard=false)
>
> 2018-06-12 13:08:41,205 DEBUG [pool-10-thread-8]
>   o.o.n.j.i.DefaultJmxCollector: Collecting ObjectName
>   com.example:name=notifyFailedTriggers
>
> 2018-06-12 13:08:41,328 DEBUG [pool-10-thread-8]
>   o.o.n.j.i.DefaultJmxCollector: ObjectName
>   com.example:name=notifyFailedTriggers is not registered.
>
> 2018-06-12 13:08:41,329 DEBUG [pool-10-thread-8]
>   o.o.n.j.i.DefaultJmxCollector: Skip ObjectName
>   com.example:name=notifyFailedTriggers
>
> 2018-06-12 13:08:41,510 INFO  [Collectd-Thread-15-of-50]
>   o.o.n.c.CollectableService: run: finished collection for
>   3/xx.xx.84.122/onms-poc/example1
>
> 2018-06-12 13:08:41,510 DEBUG [Collectd-Thread-15-of-50]
>   o.o.n.s.LegacyScheduler: schedule: Adding ready runnable
>   CollectableService for service 3:/xx.xx.84.122:onms-poc (ready in
>   300000ms) at interval 300000

This is a standalone java application that is exposing the MXBeans.

Is there a specific reason why it considers this MXBean to be unregistered and hence skipping it?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, it considers the MXBean to be unregistered if the MBean server says that it is. You may need to configure the application to enable certain beans, or perhaps the version of the application that you're using does not support the particular bean in question.

Behind the curtain, the JMX collector asks the MBean server whether the object is registered. If the MBean server responds that it is not, the JMX collector logs the message you pasted. Here's the [JMX collector code](https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/blob/opennms-22.0.0-1/core/jmx/impl/src/main/java/org/opennms/netmgt/jmx/impl/DefaultJmxCollector.java?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L155) where that happens, and here's the [documentation of the "isRegistered" method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#isRegistered-javax.management.ObjectName-) that it's calling to make that determination.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have exposed my MBeans as defined in the following guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html

Instead of the attributes specified here, I have exposed two attributes: one is an integer and other is a float value.

Now as described in the document, I have registered the MBean to the MBean Server. I can also view the same from a remote JConsole. Not sure why OpenNMS says it is not registered.

Comment: I'm not sure either, and my JMX-fu is currently middling at best, so I'm not sure where to steer you next. Typically any attribute that's accessible from JConsole is available for collection.

Did you create your JMX collection definitions using the GUI config generator, or by hand? Also, what's the exact version of OpenNMS that you're using?

Comment: I generated the JMX configuration files manually(have verified the correctness of the files multiple times). I'm using OpenNMS Horizon version 22